# how to pass params to python tornado IOLoop run_sync(main) function

Tags: python

I am using python tornado to run non-block function, how should I pass params to main function?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tornado import ioloop, gen
import tornado_mysql
import time

@gen.coroutine
def main(index):
    conn = yield tornado_mysql.connect(host=db_host, port=3306, user=db_user, passwd=db_psw, db=db_db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = 'INSERT INTO `ctp_db`.`if1506` (`bid`) VALUES (%s)'
    yield cur.execute(sql, (index))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

Answer (score 8):

Method `IOLoop.run_sync()` аccepts reference to a function and tries to invoke it.

So, if you want to run non-blocking function with specified params, you should wrap it with another function.

You can do this using additional function, the both examples  below are correct:

```
def run_with_args(func, *args):
    return func(*args)

ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(run_with_args(main, index))
```

The shorter way with `lambda`:

```
ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: main(index))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `functools.partial`
for example:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

@gen.coroutine
def func():
    print('this is the %(name)s'%{'name': func.__name__})
    yield gen.sleep(6.0)
    print('%(num)d'%{'num': 10})


@gen.coroutine
def foo():
    print('this is the %(name)s'%{'name': foo.__name__})
    yield gen.sleep(1.5)
    print('%(num)d'%{'num': 5})


@gen.coroutine
def call():
    yield gen.sleep(0)
    print('this is the callback')


@gen.coroutine
def main(ioloop):
    ioloop.call_later(5, call)
    yield [func(), foo()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from functools import partial
    ioloop = IOLoop.current()
    main = partial(main, ioloop=ioloop)
    ioloop.run_sync(main)
```